# good reading or essay on math

Tags: reference-request

I am a Chinese, who do not have knowledge with university-level mathematics.

I am looking for reading or essay on university-level math (not text which is mainly written the theory). For example, set theory, number theory, algebra, analysis, history of mathematics.

Comment: You want those bundled books like *What is Mathematics?* or *Mathematics, form and function*?

Comment: William Dunham has some great books, like The Calculus Gallery.

Answer (score 1):

You might like to read:

- [*Essays on mathematics*](http://cunymath.commons.gc.cuny.edu/for-students/essays/)
- [*Number Theory Essays*](http://www.rzuser.uni-heidelberg.de/~ci3/manu.html)
- [*Papers on History of Mathematics*](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~cherlin/History/papers.html)
- [*List of important publications in mathematics*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_important_publications_in_mathematics)

Enjoy!